# Skippmissing matrices in Julia Lang

Tags: julia, missing-data

I have variables contains matrices

```
x = [1 2 3; 3 4 5; missing missing missing]
```

How can I skip `missing` and return the values as matrices like this?

```
x = [1 2 3; 3 4 5]
```

Comment: are `missing` values always in a full line ? how do you want to deal with single `missing` values ?

Comment: There's too little information to reconstruct the shape. You could have a general case like `[1 missing; missing 4]` -- what do you want to happen then?

Comment: Yes the missing are always in a full line.

Comment: In that case it would be enough to check just fo the first value in my answer `vcat((row' for row in eachrow(x) if ! ismissing(row[1]))...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want to construct a `Matrix` without rows having no missing value you could do something like this:

```
julia> vcat((row' for row in eachrow(x) if any(.! ismissing.(row)))...)
2×3 Matrix{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1  2  3
 3  4  5
```